# Create device not working - eclipse AVD manager

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I need to test my android application with Galaxy S7 Edge. I downloaded Samsung Emulator Skin from Samsung developer site and add it to Android SDK > Platforms > android-v > skins. I tried version 14,15,19. Then in eclipse Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager and open 'create device' and filled as follow.

[image]
Here create button is active but nothing happend after click even I'm not getting any error message. I'm using  eclipse Kepler.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. I hope you've fixed it by now. However, I think I figured it out. That appears to be the screen when you try to create it from the AVD Manager. What I did was go to Android Studio > Tools > AVD Manager and installed it from there.